# calling actionscript function from javascript from frame within frame

Tags: javascript, flash

Here's the issue. We have web site with 3 frames. In 2 frames there's UI elements which cause javascript call functions within swf file. So far it has worked like this:

if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {

```
                parent.parent.document.getElementById("framename").contentWindow.document.getElementById("swf_name").function();

            } else {

                parent.parent.document.getElementById("framename").contentDocument["swf_name"]..function();
```

This worked. Yey. Except that one client has bit more unusual system where they have their own web page with frames with links to their tools. Including our web page which is loaded into one of their frames. This causes above line to fail.

How to access that swf file? Preferably without having to know the name/id of frame from within our page lies.
                }

Comment: try using `window.top` i.e. 
`if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
window.top.document.getElementById("framename").contentWindow.document.getElementById("swf_name").function();

            } else {

               window.top.document.getElementById("framename").contentDocument["swf_name"]..function();`

Comment: good thing is it still works like that when using without the extra frame(and is cleaner). Bad news is didn't solve when I added extra frameset :-/ HOWEVER when I added getElementById("the outerlayer") between document and getElementById it works.

Comment: Problem being this becomes nightmare to maintain if we get MORE customers with this system :-/